# adding php to html frame

Tags: php, html, frame

I have a problem with adding php into html which includes frame. Here is my code;

```
    <?php
    session_start();
if (($_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "normal") ||($_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "admin" )) {
?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./login.html">
    <?php}else {?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>METU 3D Panaromic View</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bar and preview images for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (Google App Engine, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="upload/css/style.css">
<!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
<!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="upload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <frameset rows="40px,94%" BORDER=2 >
        <frame src="./normal_menu.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" name="menu"/>
        <frameset cols="25%,75%" BORDER=2>
           <frame src="./map3.php?type=1" name="MAP" />
           <frame src="./view.html?fileName=findik.den.jpg" name="VIEW"/>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php}?>
```

It does not see if in php, hence it always redirects to login.html. How can i handle it without giving up frame.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you already know, but only using sessions to identify who's a admin is not a secure way of doing this. For testing purposes etc it might be just fine but keep it in mind. Your code would be vulnerable to (for instance) XSS.

Comment: Sessions are fine here. There's no way for a client to directly modify the content of the session. Additionally, XSS is irrelevant -- the HTML being outputted is all constant.

Comment: The problem was about extension of my file. It was html and it did not redirect when i changed it to php it worked. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should **really** be using the PHP [`header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function instead of the HTML `<meta>` tag:

```
header('Location:login.html');
```

The way you are currently doing it, you're risking sending content to the client that they should not have access to, and just then redirect.

Apart from that, **I think your actual problem is the boolean logic**, it seems you should be using a boolean AND, not an OR:

```
if (($_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "normal") && ($_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "admin" )) {
```

Comment: I know, I'm writing my answer in steps

Comment: Conditions may be wrong but it is not the reason if it. I changed condition to (!isset($_SESSION['user']), but result did not change.

Comment: @sinan, that, or it is set to an empty string. Did you try `empty()`? Anyway, do the print_r suggested by duskwuff, it will tell you exactly what you have in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: The problem was about extension of my file. It was html and it did not redirect when i changed it to php it worked. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional here doesn't make sense:

```
if (($_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "normal") ||($_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "admin" )) {
```

One of these two conditions will **always** be true -- `$_SESSION['accesslevel']` will always be either not-equal to "normal", or not-equal to "admin". (It can't be equal to both.)

You probably mean something like:

```
if (!($_SESSION['accesslevel'] == "normal" || $_SESSION['accesslevel'] != "admin")) {
```

Comment: Conditions may be wrong but it is not the reason if it. I changed condition to (!isset($_SESSION['user']), but result did not change.

Comment: If that's the case, I suspect that the information you're expecting in `$_SESSION` simply isn't there. You may want to try running a script with `print_r($_SESSION)` to see what (if anything) is in the session.

Comment: No, it is really not the condition or session problem. It doesn't see php code when there is a frame.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; PHP doesn't know (or care!) that your document happens to contain frames. \\ Are you certain that the file is being parsed as PHP at all? Try replacing the meta redirect with something inert, then running a "view source". If you see PHP, it's not being executed.

Comment: The problem was about extension of my file. It was html and it did not redirect when i changed it to php it worked. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.
Array $_SESSION is empty!
According with php manual (session_start section),
"The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling."
So, if you don't have any previous session going on, it seems that array $_SESSION is never populated and any test you make on it will not give any usefull result.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['accesslevel']) && !(($_SESSION['accesslevel'] == "normal") || ($_SESSION['accesslevel'] == "admin" ))) {
?>
```

Comment: Conditions may be wrong but it is not the reason if it. I changed condition to (!isset($_SESSION['user']), but result did not change.